# Did alchemy originate from the ancient Greeks?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, ancient-philosophy, greeks

Did alchemy originate from the ancient Greeks? I heard alchemy is based on ancient Greek philosophy. Is this true?

Comment: No, it can be traced to traditions independently originating in ancient China, India and Hellenistic Egypt, see [Alchemy: history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemy#History).

Comment: @Conifold Hellenistic Egypt is an ancient Greek place composed of ancient Greeks practicing ancient Greek science. Hellenistic Egypt is not native Egyptian. Hellenistic Egypt has nothing to do with native Egypt.

Comment: Hellenistic Egypt was not composed of ancient Greeks, most of the population was native. It was under Greek cultural influence mixed with influences of other cultures affected by the Alexandrian conquests, including Egyptian, Babylonian and Persian. *Hermetica* reflects this eclectic mix.

Comment: Most postulates of alchemy come out of a medieval application of the Aristotelian and platonic works translated into Latin and applied as a sort of natural philosophy. So more of a synthesis of medieval European catholic scholasticism and late dark age readings of Classical Greek works from monestaries and trade with the post first crusade Mediterranean. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Alchemy is not one thing. The Daoist alchemy tradition was responsible for the discovery of gunpowder, and magnetic compasses. Needless to say, they were not inspired by the Hellenes.

Alchemy is widely considered proto-chemistry. It's difficult to define when chemical reactions were being created that couldn't be from trial and error. Maybe in dying, and metallurgy. I would say more important to the founding of a specific chemical-discipline, were 'flamboyant' chemical reactions like [Greek fire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire) or gunpowder, because these pointed towards the hidden power of chemicals. Turning lead into gold would be arguably the most extreme example, if it were possible.

Scholars date the beginning of Western alchemy not to the Greek era, but [to Roman times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemy#Hellenistic_Egypt), influenced majorly by Egyptian thought, as well as Hellenic psycho-theology. The mythological [Hermes-Trismegistos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes_Trismegistus) seems to be an example of synchretism as Hellenes took on Egyptian thought. Lead-into-gold was the earliest & defining aim, but a cure for ageing, a universal antidote to poisons, and a universal solvent, were other aims. And inward interpretations of these as spiritual development/s were always involved. Alchemy is full of appeals to figures of antiquity, and it certainly leaned on ancient Greeks to draw lustre. But did not draw on them meaningfully for their philosophical ideas.

So I'd say no, it traces from Egyptian goldsmiths, via Roman era Hellenes.

Comment: Please leave a comment why when down-voting, so any issues can be addressed or discussed.