# Where can I learn more about Ancient Egyptian philosophy?

Tags: reference-request, ancient-philosophy

So far, I've read the [***Ancient Egyptian philosophy***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_philosophy) article on wiki. Are there other sources where I can learn about this arcane and hazy subject?

Comment: You might do better looking for "wisdom literature".

Comment: Very hard to assess... see [Book of Thoth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Thoth): "a name given to many ancient Egyptian texts supposed to have been written by Thoth ([an ancient Egyptian deity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoth)), the Egyptian god of writing and knowledge." Very few extant fragments of the purported text of the [Ptolemaic period (305 BC)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_Kingdom#History).

Comment: "The church father [Clement of Alexandria (c. 150 – c. 215 AD)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clement_of_Alexandria), in the sixth book of his work *Stromata*, mentions forty-two books used by Egyptian priests that he says contain "the whole philosophy of the Egyptians". Can you imagine what does it mean a "testimony" of some millenia later...

Comment: Some interesting speculation on the question of whether speculative Egyptian thought (somewhat on the border of philosophy and religion) may have inspired ideas in early Greek philosophy: https://philosophynow.org/issues/128/Does_Western_Philosophy_Have_Egyptian_Roots

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_Texts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Dead

Answer (score 0):

Egyptian thought is very interesting.

The first people with a symbol for zero: [Why was the zero not discovered long ago or in the beginning?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70332/why-was-the-zero-not-discovered-long-ago-or-in-the-beginning/70336#70336)

Originators of the alchemical tradition: [Did alchemy originate from the ancient Greeks?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81351/did-alchemy-originate-from-the-ancient-greeks/81354#81354)

The first monotheistic tradition: [Was the ancient Jewish concept of God utterly unique?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87352/was-the-ancient-jewish-concept-of-god-utterly-unique/87365#87365)

They developed the first true beer, drunk separated from the malt. A special red beer made with dates produced by the state, estimated to have been up to 6.5% ABV, is thought to have been crucial motivating currency to build the pyramids. It is notable that the Bronze Age is defined by the spread of Bell-Beaker culture - that is, the spread of brewing along with smithing.

Basically we lack primary texts though, so we have to look at indirect influences. In many ways Egypt broke new ground for humanity intellectually, and I'd say deserves special consideration and interest. The library and museum complex at Alexandria grew out of this culture and respect for knowledge.

Comment: Which of your statements refers to the OP's question on philosophy?

Comment: But if with "alchemy" you refer to [Hermetic tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeticism) this is not Ancient Egypt but Hellenistic, and thus is post-Greek.

Comment: @JoWehler: The one about not having primary texts.

Comment: @CriglCragl Thanks. Then: Much Ado About Nothing :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I don't think it's reasonable to picture an intellectual and cultural discontinuity in Egypt when the Hellenes arrived. Thoth was Egyptian, and I would describe hermeticism as the synchretism of Egyptian ideas with Greek forms.

Answer (score 0):

A brief note is all I have to offer (cobbled together from my random, haphazard readings):

**Egyptian Philosophy**

1. Metaphysics: Their *ontology* was typical of the age (souls, gods, spirits, etc.) and I suspect this stems from lack of clarity about *possibility vs. necessity* . Their beliefs about *causation* seem to have encompassed astrology, again a very common feature of that era. As for *identity & change*, all I can say is the Nile broke its banks on a regular basis, in the process erasing land boundaries. This required Egyptians to develop geometry, specifically *area* calculations. So the *identity* of my land was a specific number of acres, it wasn't a particular plot, say, adjoining the temple to Aten; the Nile was an agent of *change* which the Egyptians (god bless them) had to deal with annually. Egyptian geometry boils down to understanding *space*. As for *time*, I'd point to the Pyramids (structures that were unbeaten in scale until the 1800s). The level of coordination required to build the Pyramids suggest, if not prove, that they had a sophisticated notion of time (level of precision would be about 1 hour I suppose).
2. Epistemology, Logic: If I believes in *spirits*, what might that say about my epistemology and ... logic? If I can do math, what conclusion could you draw regarding my grasp of logic?
3. Ethics: They knew about *The Golden Rule*, which is, *Do unto others as you would have others do unto you*. They had a legal system, but they kept slaves and actively enslaved conquered peoples.
4. Aesthetics: The symbol for zero was a *lotus* flower. Their word for it was *Nfr*, which meant *beautiful*.

That's all folks ....